# `uninitialized constant Rake` in rake spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, rspec2

According to this tutorial http://carlosplusplus.github.io/blog/2014/02/01/testing-rake-tasks-with-rspec/

to test rake tasks with rspec, one has to set

```
Rake.application = rake
```

in a before block.
However, I get the error

```
Failure/Error: Rake.application = rake
NameError:
uninitialized constant Rake
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `require "rake"` before the offending code. The tutorial you are using is based on [a blog post by Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/test-rake-tasks-like-a-boss), which includes the appropriate require and can be used as an example.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I didn't try this because before the branch merge it worked without `require 'rake'` for some reason, but now I added it and all seems to work :)

Comment: @YoLudke You might consider just switching over to the Thoughtbot tutorial entirely. Nothing against the carlosplusplus tutorial, but Thougtbot's stuff is typically quite good.